# How do i solve this integral? $\int$ $\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this integral
$\displaystyle \int \frac{\,dx}{x^2+x+1}$?

Comment: you can use `\mathop{dx}` instead of the weird `\,dx`

Comment: @zwim If you adopt that as general practice, any punctuation placed to the right of the differential is spaced incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: By completing the square we have $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})^2$, and 
$$\int\frac{1}{u^2+a^2}\,du=\tfrac{1}{a}\,\tan^{-1}\big(\tfrac{u}{a}\big)+c.$$

So what should you take $u=\dots$?

Comment: how did you get (√3/2)^2?

Comment: Well, I got $\frac34$, but since I want something which looks like $u^2+a^2$, I thought "what, when squared, becomes $\frac34$?", the answer to which is $\sqrt{\frac34}=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt4}=\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: ahh i see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{u^2+a^2}\mathop{du}=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)}{a}+C, a\in\mathbb{R}$

$\displaystyle x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$

Now substitute in $u=x+\frac{1}{2}$ and $a^2=\frac{3}{4}$.